# Stop QGIS from loading certain ArcGIS zoom levels

Tags: qgis

I'm connected to an ArcGIS REST server, and I'm having an issue where the server has 20 zoom levels, but the last two (18 and 19) are actually just transparent. How can I get QGIS to ignore those two zoom levels and just load up to 17?

Comment: I don't know arcgis rest server, do you add the layer via WMS?

Comment: No, the layer was added as a "ArcGIS REST Servers"